# Как сделать чтобы canvas занимал только часть экрана

Tags: android, android-xml

Как сделать чтобы canvas занимал только часть экрана?
Если сделать так

```
 setContentView(new DrawView(this))
```

то весь экран будет занимать канва. Мне надо рисунок только на пол экрана, а ниже текст.

Comment: Канвас любого размера в Андроид студио будет по определению занимать часть экрана. Остальные части будут занимать элементы интерфеса АС. А если у вас вопрос про приложение для андроида, то не надо спрашивать про АС.

Comment: просто сделайте xml-разметку и в нее поместите свой кастомный класс DrawView, которому на разметке определите нужное место

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте на макет linear или Vertical layout, создайте класс для рисования (можно и другой):

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        int x = 20;
        int y = 20;
        int width = 300;
        int height = 200;
        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

или какой там выберете, а в активности вызовите новый экземпляр этого класса например так:

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
LinearLayout lay1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin2);
        lay1.addView(new CustomDrawableView(this));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не решает проблему вопроса - если в разметке больше ничего нет, то канва всё равно займёт весь контейнер. Лучше вписать этот класс прямо в макет и назначить ему расположение соответствующими атрибутами. Вы просто рисуете овал, который на разных экранах займёт разное пространство, где-то вообще не поместится.